# I am unable to copy the contents of files.000 over to another computer using Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery

My system admin has recovered a whole bunch of files in a `found.000` folder, which contains 70 subfolders, like this:

```
found.000
  xxx0000.chk
  xxx0001.chk
  ...
  xxx0069.chk
```

Each of these 70 `.chk` folders contains one or more recovered files and even some entire recovered folders from a corrupted hard disk.

Now here is the problem. I want to copy this entire structure over to another computer. So let's say I have an external attached hard drive and I copy `files.000` over to this external hard drive. When I disconnect the external hard drive from the computer which contained the original `files.000` folder and attach it to a different computer, I cannot see the `files.000` folder that I have copied on to the external drive!

If I take the external hard drive and plug it back into the original computer that contained the original `files.000` file, then I *can* see the copy of the `files.000` that I have created on the external hard drive!

What is going on?? And no, this is *not* a permissions problem, we have verified that.

Comment: What are the file attributes of that directory? Attributes get often overlooked after checking ACLs.

Comment: Have you tried zipping the structure? Which does of course not explain your issue, but maybe gets you around it. Also have you verified your "blind" system is set to show hidden and system files?

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for the quick responses. It very well could be an attribute problem. It's not an issue of hidden/unhidden because my admin told me to do the CONTROL PANEL -> FOLDER OPTIONS -> VIEW -> SHOW HIDDEN FILES AND FOLDERS thing and that did not change anything.

Comment: Drop to a command prompt and use "Attrib" to see hidden files, or just try to CD into the Files.000 folder and see if it lets you in.

Comment: I don't have xp handy, but isn't there a separate option for "hide operating system files" which is independent from "show hidden"? (there is in win7, but can't recall if that existed in winxp)

Comment: @horatio: yeah, i think so too. there are two options, one is a radio button and the other is a checkmark. in the same folder options list.

Comment: @horatio I am reading about the ATTRIBUTE called SYSTEM right now. And yes, that would make a file or folder invisible even if the show hidden files and folders option is enabled.

Comment: @notyetagm: find the second option, attribute "system" and "hide operating system files" sounds kinda promising if i am any judge. Or change the attributes if that is easier. `dir /AS` on a command prompt (in the right folder) should show you the files with the SYSTEM attribute set regardless of the folder options.  ;-)

Comment: a quick search suggests that "yes" .chk files (and the parent folders) are created as system files and are hidden when "protected OS files" are set to hidden.

Comment: @horati Thanks again. I am pretty you have solved our problem. I am going to go try your solution this afternoon.

Comment: @horatio You hit the nail on the head. As soon as I enabled viewing SYSTEM files, everything showed up. We knew the data was there because we saw the Windows prompt indicating progress as we were copying the files over but we could never see them on the other system. The original system was set to display SYSTEM files, the other system was not. Thanks again so much. :-)

Comment: SOLUTION -> the problem was that the folder found.000 and all of its .chk subfolders and files had the attribute SYSTEM set. Removing this attribute made everything visible. You can also go into FOLDER OPTIONS and have Windows show SYSTEM files by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hidden, and a System attribute; Windows XP hides these files *for you* be default. To enable displaying them, you can do one of two things:

### On the hard drive itself

1. Open the Command Prompt (**Start**->**Run**->`cmd`->**OK**)
2. `CD /d x:` (replace `x:` with the drive letter of the external hard drive) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `attrib -s -h files.000 /s /d` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This command removes the HIDDEN and SYSTEM attributes on the folder,  and all files/folders below it. This will appear properly on all Windows systems now, not as hidden.

### On the computer itself

1. Open the Folder Options (**Start**->**Control Panel**->**Folder Options**)
2. On the *View* tab, scroll down to the section about viewing *Hidden Files and Folders*. Make sure they are visible.
3. Scroll down to *Hide protected Operating System files*, and uncheck that; you'll be asked to confirm, just say **Yes**.
4. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the changes.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great explanation and solution, @Canadian Luke.